# stream2es Exception in thread error

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm facing some errors after launching a script which converts the Enron email dataset (actually just one folder to make the computation faster) into mbxox format then into JSON format. The script finishes indexing the JSON file into Elasticsearch with `stream2es` utility, in particular with this command:
`stream2es stdin --target $es_host/enron/email < enron.mbox.json`. Here come some errors which I'm going to paste here:

This is the first:

```
Exception in thread "indexer 1" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: clj-http: 
status 400 {:request-time 6, :repeatable? false, :streaming? true, 
:chunked? true, :headers {"content-type" "application/json; charset=UTF-
8", "transfer-encoding" "chunked"}, :orig-content-encoding nil, :status 
400, :length -1, :body "{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":

[{\"type\":\"action_request_validation_exception\",\"reason\":\"Validation 
Failed: 1: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;2: an 
id must be provided if version type or value are set;
```

and so on increasing the number so `3: id must be provided if version type or value are set; 4: ...` etc

Then the this one:

```
\"},\"status\":400}", :trace-redirects ["http://localhost:9200/enron/email/_bulk"]}
    at slingshot.support$stack_trace.invoke(support.clj:201)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_exceptions$fn__2502.invoke(client.clj:196)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_accept$fn__2662.invoke(client.clj:565)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_accept_encoding$fn__2668.invoke(client.clj:579)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_content_type$fn__2657.invoke(client.clj:555)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_form_params$fn__2739.invoke(client.clj:726)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_nested_params$fn__2753.invoke(client.clj:756)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_method$fn__2709.invoke(client.clj:670)
    at clj_http.cookies$wrap_cookies$fn__207.invoke(cookies.clj:124)
    at clj_http.links$wrap_links$fn__1129.invoke(links.clj:51)
    at clj_http.client$wrap_unknown_host$fn__2762.invoke(client.clj:776)
    at clj_http.client$post.invokeStatic(client.clj:891)
    at clj_http.client$post.doInvoke(client.clj:887)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
    at stream2es.http$post.invokeStatic(http.clj:21)
    at stream2es.http$post.invoke(http.clj:20)
    at stream2es.es$post.invokeStatic(es.clj:54)
    at stream2es.es$post.invoke(es.clj:48)
    at stream2es.es$error_capturing_bulk.invokeStatic(es.clj:61)
    at stream2es.es$error_capturing_bulk.invoke(es.clj:60)
    at stream2es.main$index_bulk.invokeStatic(main.clj:147)
    at stream2es.main$index_bulk.invoke(main.clj:138)
    at stream2es.main$start_indexer_pool$disp__7280.invoke(main.clj:174)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The result is that no JSON document is imported into Elasticsearch leaving the index which I created empty.

How can I fix this error?

EDIT:

Here is a sample of a single email:

```
Message-ID: <20379972.1075855673249.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Fri, 10 Dec 1999 07:00:00 -0800 (PST)
From: phillip.allen@enron.com
To: naomi.johnston@enron.com
Subject: 
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Phillip K Allen
X-To: Naomi Johnston
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \Phillip_Allen_Dec2000\Notes Folders\Discussion threads
X-Origin: Allen-P
X-FileName: pallen.nsf

Naomi,

The two analysts that I have had contact with are Matt Lenhart  and Vishal 
Apte.
Matt will be represented by Jeff Shankman.
Vishal joined our group in October.  He was in the Power Trading Group for 
the first 9 months.
I spoke to Jim Fallon and we agreed that he should be in the excellent 
category.  I just don't want Vishal 
to go unrepresented since he changed groups mid year.

Call me with questions.(x37041)

Phillip Allen
West Gas Trading
```

This is the first email document of enron.mbox.json:

```
{"X-cc": "", "From": "phillip.allen@enron.com", "X-Folder": 
"\\Phillip_Allen_Dec2000\\Notes Folders\\Sent", "Content-Transfer-
Encoding": "7bit", "X-bcc": "", "X-Origin": "Allen-P", "To": 
["hunter.shively@enron.com"], "parts": [{"content": "address:    
http://ectpdx-sunone.ect.enron.com/~ctatham/navsetup/index.htm\n\n\nid:   
pallen\npassword:  westgasx\n\n", "contentType": "text/plain"}], "X-
FileName": "pallen.nsf", "Mime-Version": "1.0", "X-From": "Phillip K 
Allen", "Date": "Fri, 26 May 2000 06:10:00 -0700", "X-To": "Hunter S 
Shively", "Message-ID": "<9828759.1075855684309.JavaMail.evans@thyme>", 
"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=us-ascii", "Subject": ""}
```

Comment: Can you show a single document that is being indexed?

Comment: Also which ES version are you using?

Comment: @Val Do you mean a single email file?

Comment: the ES version is 5.2.2 and concerning the single document, they are too long to be posted here in a comment

Comment: Cool, then update your question with a single email document.

Comment: The error occurs because you're using ES 5. It wouldn't error out with ES 2. Can you downgrade to ES 2.4?

Comment: I don not know. I just downloaded this version of EL from the official sit

Comment: Do you feel like modifying the `mailboxes__jsonify_mbox.py` Python script?

Comment: Can you update your question with the first email document you find in `enron.mbox.json` ?

Comment: I'm ready to modify the `mailboxes__jsonify_mbox.py` if it's necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the `stream2es` utility is trying to index new documents using the `create` operation but without giving an ID. This is [not allowed in ES 5 anymore](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21535).

You can [downgrade to ES 2.4.5](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-4-5) and it will work. (See [related issue](https://github.com/elastic/stream2es/issues/67))